# Change default input device from microphone to speakers

Tags: c++, macos, core-audio, portaudio

I'm using PortAudio on mac OS, hence with CoreAudio interface.

Looking at [this code](https://github.com/EddieRingle/portaudio/blob/master/examples/paex_record.c) from the official documentation, there is a function `Pa_GetDefaultInputDevice()` that returns the default input device on the computer, i.e. the microphone.

The piece of code actually records input from the microphone and then play it back.

I'd like to modify the **input device** and use the **speakers** as an input, i.e. record the sound from the computer for X seconds and play it back after.

How can I achieve that with PortAudio / CoreAudio?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  Speakers are an output device, not an input device (as seem by Core Audio on stock OS X).  If you want to tap generic speaker output, you may need to create and install a custom audio IO driver into macOS.  That's well below the level of PortAudio/CoreAudio.

Comment: Would it be more feasible to capture the sound from a specific running application then?